# Set opacity of spinner after set using animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bootstrap spinner in my html, which i wish to hide show (with a slight delay to avoid flicker) then hide once the response is received from the server.

Sounds basic.

I'm able to change the opacity to 1, but resetting it to 0 is not working as expected- although the property opacity of the element is 0, it is still visible.

```
spinnerElement = $(event.target).siblings(".spinner-border");

if (spinnerElement) {
  // display spinner element
  spinnerElement.delay(500).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);

}

// submit data via ajax
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: { 'foo': 'bar' },
  success: function () {
    // Hide spinner
    if (spinnerElement) {
      spinnerElement.css({ opacity: 0 });
    }
    //  ... successful stuff
  },
  error: function (xhr) {
    //  ... unsuccessful stuff
    // Hide spinner
    if (spinnerElement) {
      console.log(spinnerElement.css('opacity')) // 1
      spinnerElement.css({ opacity: 0 });
      console.log(spinnerElement.css('opacity')) // 0
    }
  }
});
```

These are the properties on the element.

[image]

Why is this happening? I imagine that it's somethig to do with the animate/delay property, what is the correct way to deal with this?

Comment: Your ajax request probably returned success before 500 was up. You could just simply hide the spinner, then show spinner just before the ajax call and then hide it on success or failure. You can't sync it with a fixed number delay

Comment: @Huangism i was trying to avoid the flicker effect of a super quick on/off- any ideas on fading in/out or reducing this effect?

Comment: What about `spinnerElement.stop().css({ opacity: 0 });`

Comment: I am unsure of what flicker effect you are referring to. Is it an animation or something? is it possible to replicate the flicker thing on here? only the flicker part, I think that's the root of the issue

Comment: @Huangism i meant the spinner appearing, then disappearing really quickly, the effect seems a bit abrupt, but no worries because:

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio that worked a treat, if you want to add the answer the points are yours

Comment: @User632716 allright :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can use `jQuery.stop()` to clear any ongoing animation on the element, before applying new css:

```
spinnerElement.stop().css({ opacity: 0 });
```